# Bit field specialization in python

Tags: python, ctypes, bit-fields, sign-extension

Here is a code in C++:

```
void sign_extending(int x)
{
  int r; // resulting sign extended number goes here
  struct {signed int x:5 ;} s;
  r = s.x = x;
  cout << r; 
}

void Run()
{
  int x=29; // this 29 is -3 ( 11101 ) in 5 bits 
  // convert this from using 5 bits to a full int
  sign_extending(x);
}
```

The output of this code is -3. When i try to reproduce this code in python the bit field of 11101 is generated but when the answer is converted to an int the answer of 29 is given .

the following is code of python:

```
from bitarray import *

def sign_extending(x) :
  s = bitarray(5)
  r = s = bin(x)  #resulting sign extended number goes in r
  print (int(r, 2))

x = 29 #this 29 is -3 ( 11101 ) in 5 bits. Convert this from using 5 bits to a full int
sign_extending(x)
```

I also used ctypes structures as an alternative code but no use :

```
from ctypes import *
def sign_extending(x, b):
  class s(Structure):
      _fields_ = [("x", c_int, 5)]
  r = s.x = x
  return r  #resulting sign extended number goes in r

x = 29; #this 29 is -3 ( 11101 ) in 5 bits. 
r = sign_extending(x, 5) #Convert this from using 5 bits to a full int
print r
```

My question is that how would i produce this result using bit arrays or any other method that gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `s` is a class and the class `x` member actually represents the field type, so assigning `s.x = 29` essentially destroys that object and assigns a normal Python int to it.  Example:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class S(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [('x',c_int,5)]
... 
>>> S.x
<Field type=c_long, ofs=0:0, bits=5>
>>> S.x = 29
>>> S.x
29
```

Also, even if you create an instance first, `r = s.x = 29` does not do `s.x = 29` then `r = s.x` as in C/C++ but essentially `r=29` and `s.x=29`.  Example:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class S(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [('x',c_int,5)]
...     
>>> s=S()
>>> r=s.x=29
>>> s.x
-3
>>> r
29
```

So to fix, instantiate the class, assign `s.x = 29` and return it:

```
from ctypes import *
def sign_extending(x, b):
    class S(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("x", c_int, b)]
  s=S()
  s.x = x
  return s.x

x = 29; #this 29 is -3 ( 11101 ) in 5 bits. 
r = sign_extending(x, 5) #Convert this from using 5 bits to a full int
print r
```

Output:

```
-3
```

Comment: thank you for the answer i will mark it as correct. Also just out of curiosity how would i do the same thing using bitarrays?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might possibly do what you want (as long as x is non-negative and can be written using b bits).

```
def sign_extend(x, b):
    if x >= 2 ** (b - 1):
        return x - 2 ** b
    else:
        return x
```

Comment: your answer is right but i was hoping to get a solution by using the bitarray or the structure code. As it would make more sense to use bit fields as stated in the c++ code given

Comment: Note that `1 << n` is _much_ faster than `2 ** n`.